# settext to uitextview app crash - ios sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, settext, uitextviewdelegate

I have created `UITextView` programatically, textview is created as required but when i try to set value for textview using tag application crashes.

I am able to set other parameter like `setUserInteractionEnabled` without issue.

following the code for it..

To create textview

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,200)];
    textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
    //textView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    textView.tag=i;
    [textView setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    textView.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
    textView.inputView= [LNNumberpad defaultLNNumberpad];
    textView.editable = YES;
    [textView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
```

Changeing value in textview using tag..

```
UITextView *txtviewfound = (UITextView *)[self.view viewWithTag:j];
            [txtviewfound setText:@"some text"];
            [txtviewfound setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE];
```

When i comment settext like it works fine.

If i am missing anything please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i and j has integer value and its in loop till 5 @Sunny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Before type casting you need to check weather subview belongs to
>   textView Or not,because by default every object having 0 as a tag
>   value.if you have any other objects are in your view then it'l creates
>   problem.

```
if([[self.view viewWithTag:i]isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])
{
            UITextView *txtviewfound = (UITextView *)[self.view viewWithTag:j];
            [txtviewfound setText:@"some text"];
            [txtviewfound setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the crash log saying? An index out if bound maybe?
Also just to be sure - don't set tags with really low numbers like 1 to 5, they could, rarely but still, already be taken by Apple.